# Switch to playlist view from D-Command

Tags: pro-tools

In Pro Tools:

I know how to switch a track to volume, pan, mute, and waveform views, but how do I get to playlist view from the D-Command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer [here](http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=291774).  Apparently there's no way to get to the expanded playlist view from the D-Command.

My illusion of the D-Command's omnipotence has been shattered.